# How to upgrade a package which has a newer version than the repository?

Tags: apt, tmux, upgrade

I've installed tmux from apt-get. I checked the version is 1.8.
But when I directly go to tmux official site, I see the latest version is 2.0.

How can I upgrade to 2.0?
`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade tmux` always tell me I've got the newest version of tmux which is wrong.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You should include some information about your operating system. As you're using apt I guess it's debian based? But are you sitting in front of a Debian/Ubuntu/Mint etc?

Comment: see answer on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940944/ugrade-tmux-from-1-8-to-1-9-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3):

There are alternative repositories from which you can install later versions of `tmux`, but they are not official. Installing from source is relatively easy:

```
# install any dependency packages needed for building
sudo apt-get install -y exuberant-ctags cmake libevent-dev libncurses5-dev
# download link from official http://tmux.github.io/ site
wget https://github.com/tmux/tmux/releases/download/2.0/tmux-2.0.tar.gz
tar xvf tmux-2.0.tar.gz
cd tmux-2.0
./configure && make
```

and if that all worked, make sure all running `tmux` sessions are stopped (because the protocol version might differ)

```
sudo apt-get remove -y tmux
sudo make install
```

Comment: don't think you need `exuberant-tags` to install tmux